# How to sort date array in VC++?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++-cli

I need to create a table. One column of the table schedule date and time. I am new to C++/CLI. The only way that I know how to find the relate the date and time is using

```
 System::DateTime newDate
```

I need to find out the schedule date in each row and sort them by the happening soon. How can I compare each DateTime object with the current time and find out which happen the soonest?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite unclear what exactly do you want, but assuming that you have a collection of objects with a `Date` property, you can do something like this:

```
IEnumerable<SomType^>^ items = …

DateTime now = DateTime::Now;

SomeType^ result = nullptr;

for each (SomeType^ item in items)
{
    if (item->Date > now && (result == nullptr || item->Date < result->Date))
        result = item;
}
```

That being said, it's probably not a good idea to learn programming in C++/CLI, I think it would be much better if you used C#, unless you have a good reason for C++/CLI.

Comment: "*it's probably not a good idea to learn programming in C++/CLI*" +1 for this sane advice.

Comment: Thanks for your advice of programming learning. The reason that I try to learn C++/CLI because I have taken 15 basic lessons of C++/CLI in last few weeks.

Comment: @user765168 : C++/CLI is the worst aspects of C++ combined with the worst aspects of .NET plus lots of compiler bugs. The only reason it's survived as a language is because it's great for interop. For code that _isn't_ interop, it's not terribly useful and has a _huge_ learning curve to use properly.